# GLEW: I set it to use the static library but at run time complains about not finding libGlew.so

Tags: opengl, static, libraries, shared, glew

I am working on a project which uses GLFW and GLEW. I can compile it perfectly without error messages but when I run it it prompts this:

```
/home/doc/main: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I added **#define GLEW_STATIC** on top of my main file, so it shouldn't find it as a shared library, should it? Do you have any idea of what could it be? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
On my Qt project file I append this into LIBS

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lGLEW
```

Comment: Something doesn't seem quite right here, did you install GLEW manually and it's lib's are not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or something?

Comment: @rogerdpack Oh man, it was 5 years ago, I'm sorry I can't remember what I was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define GLEW_STATIC` does in no way influence the linker - this is actually only needed for Windows platforms, where in the dynamic versions, `dllspec` declarations are added.

If you want to link statically to GLEW, you need a static `.lib` file and have to point your linker to link against that.

However, in the case of GLEW, you can also directly integrate `glew.c` into your project, and link the object file, so that no library is needed at all.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much it's working now. Do you know how to get a .lib version of the library? Do I get it by compiling the GLEW source code? Thanks @derhass

Comment: The default Makefile which comes with GLEW builds both a static and a dynamic version of the lib.

Comment: Oh yeah I found it sorry, as I did `make clean` I thought it wouldn't be there. Thanks a lot!